# How to check/make sure of Elasticsearch load balancer?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Nest,Asp.net Core 3.1 and Elasticsearch , I have created a 3-nodes-Cluster, with default roles.

How could I check that the queries/search queries are balanced between my local machines?

I tried to monitor metrics of each server/node while indexing large data, and I saw that only nodes having related replica and primary shard were engaged during the large indexing process.

But I need to check and make sure that the requests are balanced/divided between my nodes in a round robin manner, but I do not know how to check that? Is there any way or any tools that I make sure that for example, at first search query node-1 is engaged and at second search query node-3 is engaged?

Any hint, keyword and any help is appreciable.

My each .KML configuration : (all 3 nodes are

```
cluster.name: my-cluster
node.name: node-1
network.host: 192.168.254.137
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.254.137", "192.168.254.135", "192.168.254.136"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.254.137", "192.168.254.135", "192.168.254.136"]
```

My index is distributed as below:

```
index                           shard prirep state   docs   store ip              node

suggestionindex                 0     p      STARTED 2000 170.5kb 192.168.254.136 node-3
suggestionindex                 0     r      STARTED 2000  90.5kb 192.168.254.137 node-1
```

My appsettings.json :

```
"ElasticsearchSettings": {
 // IP of one of the 3 master eligible nodes
"uri": "http://192.168.254.137:9200/",    
"basicAuthUser": "",
"basicAuthPassword": ""
  },
```

Does all the search queries send to primary shard (node-1) always?? or the search queries are balanced between node-1 and node-3 in my case?
If it is balanced, how can I check it?
Who balances it between nodes?? Nest or my Master node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch internally load-balance the queries on all the data-nodes, so you don't have to do anything from your side, if you are on Elasticsearch version 7.X, than elasticsearch uses the [Smart load balancing technique called Adaptive replica selection](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-response-latency-in-elasticsearch-with-adaptive-replica-selection) before that by default it was based on round-robin technique.

Elastic Blog which I mentioned has all the details of its working.

Comment: Thanks. and to find that which node is responsible of which query, I used `disk/memory/cpu monitoring` in each node during the queries. and also I changed `index.search.slowlog.threshold.query` to log all my search queries and I checked my `my-cluster_index_search_slow.log`. I'll be more thankful if you know a better way that I can know which node is engaged in each query (This was my second question)

Comment: @ehsan_kabiri_33, for this you need to check the slow logs, which prints the node, shard , index and all other details related to query, you may not get it for each query and if you want for each query, you can reduce the threshold to 0ms for all search queries.

Comment: @ehsan_kabiri_33 I am just wondering what is your use-case and why you need to know that much detail for each query, you can also have a look or book a demo of https://opster.com/elasticsearch-essentials/ if you want a lot of metrics of your ES cluster.